# Single refs used by many elements

Tags: reactjs

I know this is not common case but is it possible to have case like this

```
render () {
   return (
      <div>
          blablabalblbla balbal <span ref={ el => this.title = el }></span>'s adsdasd
          <p>would sjdfdfjhdsjfjdf <span ref={ el => this.title = el }></span>?</span></p>
      </div>
   }
}
```

and later using `componentDidMount()` I set it like this

```
this.title.innerHTML = obj.title
```

now only the last element will affected. Is there any technique make it work for both elements?

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking too complicated. First off, the general consensus is to try and not use `refs` wherever possible. They're not really following the principles and concepts of React, as is setting the `innerHTML`. With React, you should try to not modify/read the DOM directly. Second, what you're describing can be solved with React's `state`. Take a look at this example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { title: 'Hello' };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }
  onChange(e) { this.setState({ title: e.target.value }); }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        blablabalblbla balbal {this.state.title}'s adsdasd
        <p>would sjdfdfjhdsjfjdf {this.state.title}?</p>
        <input onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.title} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

You can use a `state` element inside your JSX like a variable and change it in your code with `this.setState()`. React will then automatically update your component's "HTML" in the DOM.

Comment: i just thought perhaps I could minimize the use of state

Comment: Nice thinking, but then rather use a flux architecture like redux. state > refs.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.